# Export a function from a JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, export

I am trying to make a component in React that is just a function

```
import React from "react";

function TableSortFunction(data, method, column) {
  const newList = [];
  for (let i; i <= data.length; i++) {
    newList.push(data[i].column);
  }
  console.log(newList), data, method, column;
  return newList;
}

export default TableSortFunction;
```

I am importing my function in another component like this

```
import { TableSortFunction } from "./TableSortFunction";
```

but I get an error saying:

```
Attempted import error: 'TableSortFunction' is not exported from './TableSortFunction'.
```

How do I export a js file that is just a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you export it as default you have to import it like so:

```js
import TableSortFunction from "./TableSortFunction";
```

**Edit**: Another issue with your code is that the following is not syntactically correct.

```js
console.log(newList), data, method, column;
```

Try this instead:

```js
console.log(newList, data, method, column);
```

Comment: I've tried that but it creates a different error. `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression `

Comment: wait I see the problem now `console.log(newList), data, method, column;` is not syntactically correct, try `console.log(newList, data, method, column);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import TableSortFunction from "./TableSortFunction";
```

> Your console isn't correct

instead of

```
console.log(newList), data, method, column;
```

should be

```
console.log(newList, data, method, column);
```

There are two types of import - named and default.

**Export and Import function**

Export from - **say.js**

```
function sayHi(user) {
  alert(`Hello, ${user}!`);
}

function sayBye(user) {
  alert(`Bye, ${user}!`);
}

export {sayHi, sayBye};
```

Import from - **say.js** to **main.js**

```
import {sayHi, sayBye} from './say.js';

sayHi('John'); // Hello, John!
sayBye('John'); // Bye, John!
```

for better understanding, you can refer to articles.

- [Export and Import](https://javascript.info/import-export)
- [Named Export vs Default Export in ES6](https://medium.com/@etherealm/named-export-vs-default-export-in-es6-affb483a0910)

Comment: I've tried that but it creates a different error. `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression`